# Add javascript chart to gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, amcharts

I've done several searches but haven't found anything that may help me.

I have a simple gridview that displays the following data: `Sales.SalesTotal` and `Sales.Company`. This works fine.

The issue now is that I need to add a `javascript` chart to each row of this gridview. It would be something similar [to this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he2P8.png).

This javascript chart is filled with a WCF service that uses the company name (already in the `gridview` and `SqlDataSource`) as parameter. The WCF call looks like this: `http://43.32.54.23/SalesWcf.svc/GetSales/Company` where ***company*** is the name of the company in the gridview.

The problem is that I have no idea how to approach this. This is my gridview, very simple:

```
    <asp:GridView
        id="GridView_sales" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSales">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" ReadOnly="True">
                <headerStyle Width="50" Font-Names="calibri"/>
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="calibri" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesTotal" HeaderText="SalesTotal" ReadOnly="True" >
                <headerStyle Width="60" Font-Names="calibri" ForeColor="#ffffff"/>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="True" Font-Names="calibri"/>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <**** Where javascript chart goes, invoked with http://43.32.54.23/SalesWcf.svc/GetSales/Company ****/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>    
    <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSourceSales" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;..."
        SelectCommand="SELECT SalesTotal, Company from Sales">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

This is what my amcharts graph looks like:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("DivSalesChart", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1"
    }],
    "graphs": [
    {
        "id": "Company",
        "valueField": "sales_num"
    }],
    "categoryField": "month_name",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "http://43.32.54.23/SalesWcf.svc/GetSales",
      "format": "json"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a template field for rendering chart holder div with an attribute data-companyId for holding the companyId:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="salesChart" data-company='<%# Eval("Company")%>'></div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add Jquery code for finding all divs with css class salesChart and then fetch sales data by ajax call to WCF service with company name fetched from `data-company` attribut. Finally, in success callback of ajax call initiate chart on the `chartContainer` div

```
 $(function(){
        $('.salesChart').each(function(index, chartContainer){
            varcompanyName=$(chartContainer).attr('data-company');

             AmCharts.makeChart(chartContainer,
             {
                "type": "serial",
                "theme": "light",
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "id": "v1"
                }],
                "graphs": [{
                    "id": "Company",
                    "valueField": "sales_num"
                }],
                "categoryField": "month_name",
                "dataLoader": {
                    "url": "http://43.32.54.23/SalesWcf.svc/GetSales/"+ companyName,
                    "format": "json"
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited the question to show the chart code. How can this be implemented in your example?